# Fit slider image inside 950 pixels

Tags: anythingslider

I am trying to have a full width(950px) slider but i cant seem to get my

```
<ul id="slider1">

                <li><img src="images/slide-civil-1.jpg" alt="A Very Good Picture"></li>

                <li><img src="images/slide-env-1.jpg" alt=""></li>

                <li><img src="images/slide-civil-2.jpg" alt=""></li>
</ul>
```

float left.The css for slider1,`#main` `#slider1 { width: 950px; height: 390px; list-style: none; }` can increase in width but not float left.Has anyone managed to get full width to work for this slider.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear, but I'm guessing you don't want the slider to center itself? If you add the following css, it will no longer center itself ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/VM8XG/6306/)).

```
​div.anythingSlider {
    margin: 0;
}​
```

If this isn't want you wanted, please clarify your question.